# OpenSource 2 way video conferencing, LAN

Tags: conferencing

I'm looking for a 2 way IP driven Video Conferencing Application which gives me the power to rename the Application, and block users from entering other personal info or at least remove them so the users can see them, even if i need to compile it from source.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options - they are more or less opposites:

- [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) is fairly narrow - mostly, it does video calling and text chatting. (It requires no server, either)
- [openmeetings](http://openmeetings.apache.org/) has *a lot* of features. It is probably going to be more intensive [to setup](http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/installation.html), but you get a lot for doing that, and it is all self-contained.

Comment: you don't need a dedicated server for ekiga.  You can do peer-to-peer calls just fine.